# How to effectively scroll 1024x90000 image in a window?

Tags: c++, qt, audio, scroll, qimage

I have the following UI, where the sonogram (freq+time sound representation) is shown. So the image is not loaded from somewhere, it is drawn by `QPainter` while reading `WAV` file.

[image: The UI]

My current implementation is a single huge `QImage` object, where the image is drawn. And on `paintEvent()`, I draw part of the large `QImage` on the widget:

```
QPainter painter(this);
// (int, int, QImage*, int, int)
painter.drawImage(0, 0, *m_sonogram, 0, m_offset);
```

But, as i know, the `QPixmap` is optimized for displaying pixmaps on the screen, so should I convert the `QImage` to a `QPixmap` after the drawing of the sonogram is done?

Also, is it worth to keep large image as some kind of a linked list of separate `QPixmap` objects of smaller size and make `paintEvent()` smarter to operate on a list of smaller objects to avoid Qt's auto-cutting  procedures and so on?

When my QImage is large enough, each `paintEvent()` consuming a lot of `CPU`.

All kinds of advices are welcome :)

Comment: Perhaps post something about machines you want this to run on. Using linked list could be smart depending on the target machines.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but it seems you draw the entire image every paint event. You could paint only the portion of the image you're currently showing on the viewport. That's should keep CPU consuming constant.

Comment: @Masci: See the "Automatic Clipping" note in the QPaintEvent docs: Qt does this automatically and you don't need to explicity copy any QPaintEvent clipping state to your QPainter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in my limited experience of Qt app development, if you have a static image (or an infrequently updated image) it's well worth (for performance purposes) creating a `QPixmap` from it and keeping it around to use via `QPainter::drawPixmap` in your `paintEvent` handler.

However, I've never tried doing this with anything larger than about 4Kx4K images, so whether it will work for your enormous image or fall over horribly when you start to stress your graphics memory I couldn't say.  I'd certainly try it out before considering adding a complicated tiling system.